# Validate Sector of Circle

Tags: ios

I have made Circle With below code

```
//Color Declaration
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.429 blue:0 alpha:1];

    //Drawing Circle
    CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 170, 170);
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [circlePath addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circleRect), CGRectGetMidY(circleRect))
                          radius:CGRectGetWidth(circleRect)/2 startAngle:0 * M_PI/180
                        endAngle:289 * M_PI/180
                       clockwise:YES];
    [circlePath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(circleRect), CGRectGetMidY(circleRect))];
    [circlePath closePath];


    [color setFill];
    [circlePath fill];
```

I have Validated Touches Code with Area of Circle With the Below code,

```
- (BOOL)validatePoint:(CGPoint)myPoint
{
    // calculate how far from centre we are with Pythagorean
    // √ a2 + b2
    CGFloat a = abs(myPoint.x - (self.view.bounds.size.width/2));
    CGFloat b = abs(myPoint.y - (self.view.bounds.size.height/2));
    CGFloat distanceFromCentre = sqrt(pow(a,2) + pow(b,2));

    if((distanceFromCentre > self.minRadiusSize) && (distanceFromCentre < self.maxRadiusSize)){
        return YES;
    }else{
        // not inside doughnut
        return NO;
    }
}
```

I have Validated the Circle with Above code.When above code is true then we can add touches to Circle.

Similarly I have to validate the sector (Portion) of the Circle.
My Requirement is, I have to validate the Sector of Circle. were I have to Detect the sector(Portion) of the drawn Circle.
I have Formula
                `[Area of Sector = ½ × (θ × π/180) × r2   (when θ is in degrees)]`.

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14736197/1059705

Comment: How to Validate sector of Circle. and Position of Sector in Circle.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is to check if the point is inside the circle sector then you should use the same path to hit test the point

```
BOOL isInsideSector = [circlePath containsPoint:myPoint];
```